# Executing scanimage command from PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am brand new to PHP and I am trying to execute a shell command to initiate a command line scan on my Ubuntu 12.10 box:

I have the following piece of code in my php file (inside submit click handler):

```
shell_exec('scanimage --format=pdf > scan.pdf')
```

Is this even possible? I have been able to execute other terminal commands through this API. However in this case nothing happens. I am able to run the above command in a terminal window

I am trying to do the scan on form submit

```
<form method="post" action="printApp.php">
    <input type="submit" name="scan" value="Start New Scan" />

</form>



  <?
     if(isset($_POST["scan"])){
        shell_exec('scanimage --format=pdf > scan.pdf')
     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new php file called `scanimage.php` and put just

```
<?php
shell_exec('scanimage --format=pdf > scan.pdf');
?>
```

in it. Then at bash type `php scanimage.php` while in the same directory as the file.

UPDATE: After doing a chat it seems that Apache didn't have the permissions needed to access the scanner somewhere in /dev.

Comment: I wanted to do it from a webpage on button click and not involve the bash shell. Is that possible?

Comment: MAke the file as I suggested above and put it into your `public_html` so it's web accessible, then just open your browser and goto that page. Keep in mind anyone will have access to run it unless you implement additional security measures.  If you want to do it on a button click I need to see your entire file to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Hm.. I don't quite understand why I can't just do it through a form post initiated by the submit button click?

Comment: Because I haven't yet seem the form! Sorry, not to be a smart ass but serious, post your code.

Comment: If you type `scanimage --format=pdf > scan.pdf` in bash what happens?

Comment: It initiates the scan,so I am a bit confused that it doesn't work. It seems to be running under a different context through the php script. Because if I do a scanimage -L it says I don't have any devices connected.

Comment: You were right - it was a permission issue. Wasn't able to grant access to the scanner itself as I couldn't locate it :-). However by running as sudo from PHP I at least confirmed your theory that it was permission related. Will look into finding the scanner inside DEV, but for now it works as sudo. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: My pleasure. So glad I was right and that you are on the right track to getting it working.

Comment: PS have a look here for a tutorial on dealing with scanners in. Linux. http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialScanners.html.